# Omitting middle characters if string is too long when display a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

When display a DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook, if the string value is too long, the last characters will be omitted:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']})

display(df)
```

output:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST... |

I want to change the behavior and only ommit the middle characters of the string when it's too long:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW...DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |

Is it possible?

Comment: If that's possible, there's a high probability you will find it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html#pandas-set-option)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html), you can build a custom formatter.

```py
def formatter(x):
  if isinstance(x, str):
    if len(x) > pd.options.display.max_colwidth:
      display_width = pd.options.display.max_colwidth 
      split = int((display_width-3) / 2)
      if display_width % 2: # if odd number
        return x[:split] + "..." + x[-split:]
      else:
        return x[:(split+1)] + "..." + x[-split:]
    else:
      return x
  return None
```

And use it as such:

```
df.style.format(formatter)
```

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW...DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |

**This is only a display format so the data is not changed.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to omit the middle characters of the string

```
# Custom function for omitting middle characters
def omit_characters(value, max_width=40):
    if len(value) <= max_width:
        return value
    else:
        middle = max_width // 2
        return f"{value[:middle]}...{value[-middle:]}"
```

Applying the custom function to the 'A' column

```
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: omit_characters(x, max_width=40))
df
```

**Ouput**

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW...DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |